# Group observations with SQL and Specifying in same group

Tags: sql, proc-sql

I have a table consisting of two columns (X,Y) that represent correlations between observations like below.

```
X Y
1 2
2 3
3 4
A B
B C
```

I want a create new column that represent the relation between observation. 1 become 2, 2 become 3, 3 become 4. So i wanna show this variables in same group(1,2,3,4 are belong to same group). The table should be like below.

```
X Y Z 
1 2 Group 1
2 3 Group 1 
3 4 Group 1 
A B Group 2
B C Group 2
```

I am using SAS Enterprise Guide. The solution would be great with proc sql or any sql type. I need the logic.

Note: I have no additional information except this table.

Comment: I dont know `proc-sql`. In standard SQL you would write a recursive query to find all chains. Then for each chain get the minimum or maximum element as a group indicator (i.e. 1,2,3 belong to group '1' resp. '4', A, B belong to group 'A' resp. 'C').

Comment: Proc sql doesn't support recursive CTEs.  You need a data step with a loop, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7prmSZNWsDySkycwiPrDZf/1) which is in PostgreSQL but you may be able to use the same logic.

```
with cte as
(
    select
        *,
        lag(y) over (order by x) as rnk
    from myTable
)

select
    x,
    y,
    concat('Group ', sum(case when x = rnk then 0 else 1 end) over (order by x)) as z
from cte;
```

Output:

```
| x   | y   | z       |
| --- | --- | ------- |
| 1   | 2   | Group 1 |
| 2   | 3   | Group 1 |
| 3   | 4   | Group 1 |
| A   | B   | Group 2 |
| B   | C   | Group 2 |
```

Comment: This relies on distinct increasing number ranges. I don't see these guaranteed. See: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6cBEhAivT9TG9m85VHrbFx/1 or https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fy591appKwCTue1edHkjBq/1.